# How to test if my new event is working in Google TagManager before publishing it?

Tags: android, google-tag-manager

I am using Google TagManager in my android project. It was used and maintained before by someone and I am new to Google TagManager stuffs. I want to measure one of the button click events in my app. So, I have added this on button click:

```
dataLayer.push("myid", "mybutton-btn-click");
```

In Google Tag Manager also, I have added this variable and generated the new container binary which I have put in my app.

Now before publishing the container, I want to make sure that this new button click event works. But I cannot find a way to test it.

I enabled "tagManager" verbose logging but do not see any log when I click the button.

I also tried looking in GTM console and could not find a place to see it. I am also trying to look in GA console and could not see it.

I could generate the preview link for the container and can test that the app gets launched with the QR code reader.

can someone help me to know how to test if the event got logged on click of the button?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

For testing your events in an anroid you need follow the instruction available in GTM for anroid documentation
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/#preview-debug-pubish-container

Comment: Another thing to watch for is that you need to push an update including the "event" key. Pushes without the event key update the data layer's contents, but don't cause GTM to trigger any tags. This is described here: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v3/reference/com/google/tagmanager/DataLayer